# Annotation @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "msg") doesn't work with onAuthenticationFailure() method

Tags: spring, security, authentication, thymeleaf

I use Spring Security:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//...//
@Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .failureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler ())
//...//
}
```

Next:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {

redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, "/users/login");
}
```

And my login object is represented by:

```
public class LoginForm {

@Size(min = 1, max = 5, message = "min 1 and max 5")
private String username;

@Size(min = 2, max = 6, message = "min 2 and max 6")
@NotNull
private String password;
```

and part of frontend:

```
<div><label for="password" th:value="*{password}">Password:</label></div>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" th:value="*{password}"/>
<span class="formError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}"
      th:errors="*{password}">Invalid password</span>
```

My problem is that if the login form is incorrect I don't get a message on the frontend.

My attempts:

1. Like the registration (where my solution works) I tried to create my own method, something like this:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/users/login", method = RequestMethod.POST) 

   public String loginPage(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

   if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
       return "users/login";
   }

   return "redirect:/";
   }
   ```

however, the *.failureHandler(my AuthenticationFailureHandler())* method is a priority, and I see in the debugger that the program does not start my method.

2. I thought to add this information as a header/attribute but without success, something like this:

   ```
       httpServletResponse.setHeader("passwordInvalid", "true");
       httpServletRequest.setAttribute("passwordInvalid", "true");
   ```
3. Set this message by checking the contents of the input field in Thymeleaf (without backend).

2nd and 3rd solution is not OK for me because I would like to learn how to check the field and write a message on the frontend according to the information in the annotations in the LoginForm class.

My goal is also not adding any error parameter to the url - *'myurl?errorparameter'*.

I am asking for tips.

Comment: Spring Security will handle the login not your controller, so those annotations don't apply. If you want to make it work, which I suggest you don't, you need to bypass Spring Security and implement the login etc. yourself (as suggested don't do this).

Comment: Thanks for advice!